# Angular 2 Simulate API by having http requests return json files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am building an app using the Angular CLI and I've run into a problem. I am developing ahead of the API I am integrating with so I need to mock the APIs responses for the time being so I can move forward on the front end. In the past I had built an app without the CLI and had set up webpack manually so I could tell it to package certain json files and then point my API requests to those files.

However with the Angular CLI I don't see a way I can get the json packaged with the app, at least not in local development.

mock-api/user.json

```
{
  alias: 'Batman
  name: 'Bruce Wayne'
}
```

API.ts

```
export class API {
  public static USER = '/mock-api/user.json';
}
```

controller.ts

```
this.http.get(API.USER).subscribe(res => { this.user = res; });
```

I had some success adding the user.json file to the assets array in the angular-cli.json, but it only includes the file in the /dist directory after doing a ng build. However when I do ng serve for local development I get a 404 when making the request for the file. I've noticed that ng serve doesn't even create a dist directory so I'm not sure what file structure is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example of doing this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-CLI

I included the api folder containing the app's .json file in the `angular-cli.json` file:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "api",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you run the application? As I said in the question I have tired doing this and when I do ng build I see the directory copied into /dist but when I try to run the app locally with ng serve I get a 404 error when I try to load the file

Comment: I *did* have to update to the latest version of the CLI. The prior (RC) version I was using was generating lots of errors. I'm currently using 1.0.1.

Comment: Weird I was on 1.0.0, just tried 1.0.1 and still the same thing. I wonder why this is working for you but not me. It's also very weird that it works for me with ng build but not ng serve.

Comment: You can try my code if you wish. It is at the link shown above. You could compare your config and file placement to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use project call 'now' https://zeit.co/docs/examples/json-api. It is very easy and fact to simulate JSON API with it.